# How to allow only 3 digit and one dot in Regular Expression

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-material, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I want to do like this : 3.40 and not more than 3 characters and one dot:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
                    <label>Marks/CGPA</label>
                    <input type="text" name="education.cgpa" ng-model="education.cgpa"
                           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,4}$/">
                    <div class="input-validation" ng-show="educationSaveForValidate['education.cgpa'].$error.pattern">
                        Insert valid CGPA
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
```

How can I allow only 3 digits and one dot in Regular Expression?

Answer (score 3):

You may use a single regex like

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!.{5})\d*\.?\d+$/"
```

or - to allow an empty string:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!.{5})\d*\.?\d*$/"
```

You may also move the length check out of the regex:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*\.\d*$/" ng-maxlength="4"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.{5})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any 5 chars in the input string
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d*` - zero or more digits (if `\d+` is used, then **1** or more digits)
- `$` - end of string.

To disallow any leading/trailing spaces, add `ng-trim="false"`.

Comment: thanks Wiktor Stribiżew. your code does not work properly for me. but i have found a solution. this is : ng-pattern="/^\d\.\d{0,2}$/"

Comment: @monirtuhin That won't allow valid float numbers like `.123`. Also, that won't match `12.4`. And that will match `1.` (no idea if that is important here).

Comment: I wanted one digit befor dot(.) and two digit after dot(.) like (2.50) . in this way this solution helped me. thanks wiktor

Comment: @monirtuhin There are no exact requirements in the question, so my answer is valid. Yours is too restricted. If my answer helped, feel free to upvote it.

Comment: your answer also helped me to identify my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/kF0hJ5/17

Check this link above, I hope it'll help you. Sorry for commenting link here. Doing so as I have less repo.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem this way......

```
ng-pattern="/^\d\.\d{0,2}$/"
```

Comment: `/^\d\.\d{0,2}$/` won't allow valid float numbers like `.123`. Also, that won't match `12.4`. And that will match `1.` (no idea if that is important here).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew
I wanted one digit befor dot(.) and two digit after dot(.) like (2.50) . in this way this solution helped me. thanks